# How to add external SWT lib sources to Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swt

I wanna use [Eclipse SWT UI library](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) in my java project. The problem is the latest lib version isn't present at central Maven repo. So I gonna create local in-project repo and install the latest code and sources here from Eclipse SWT sight.

Eclipse SWT UI library might be downloaded as archive [swt-4.14-win32-win32-x86_64.zip](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.14-201912100610/download.php?dropFile=swt-4.14-win32-win32-x86_64.zip) and has inside `swt.jar` (binary code) and `swt.zip` (java docs)

For in-project repo I've add this definition in `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>in-project-repo</id>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
      <artifactId>swt-win32-win32-x86_64</artifactId>
      <version>4.14</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

and install here lib binary `swt.jar` with command

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -Dfile=swt.jar \
  -DgroupId=org.eclipse.swt \
  -DartifactId=swt-win32-win32-x86_64 \
  -Dversion=4.14 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -DlocalRepositoryPath=<path to my in-project repo folder>
```

*The question is how to install java docs `swt.zip` file too to allow IDE uses this sources while project browsing?*

Comment: The latest SWT lib for Maven should be here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64. They have a different version name but if you open the jars as zip you should see the same files.

Comment: @LorisSecuro it's true but... what a stupid idea to have own SWT version numbering instead of origin Eclipse numbering! Also there is only Windows SWT version - not Linux and MacOS

Comment: Linux: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64, MacOS: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64. About the version number, I agree, I don't know why they do that.